# How can I assign a variable a whole column of data and then make a table of two columns in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

This is what I have so far:

```
data<-read.csv(the right pathway)

mydata <- read.table(data, header=TRUE, sep=",",colClasses = c("datetime", "parametervalue"))

x <- mydata$column4
y <- mydata$column6

graph<-plot(x,y, 
 xlab = "x-axis", 
 ylab = "y-axis", 
 main = "Plot"+expand_limits(x=c(1980,2022),y=c(0,150))+
   scale_x_continuous("Year", breaks = c(50,100,150))+
   scale_y_continuous("Estimated data (in)", breaks = c(50,100,150)),
)
```

I tried using other solutions, but am not sure why it's not working. I keep getting the error meessage "Error in read.table(data, header = TRUE, sep = ",", colClasses = c("datetime",  :
'file' must be a character string or connection".

Comment: Hi aiqt, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. In your case, if you run `dput(data)` and add the result to your question, that will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: `read.table` expects a file name as its first argument, but you are passing it "data", which is a data frame (since it is the returned value of `read.csv`). The rest of your question is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `read.table()` takes a file path as an argument, not an object. What you're doing is reading a CSV file with `read.csv()` and then passing the data frame to the `read.table()` command, which is incorrect. When you load the data in R with `read.csv()`, what you end up with is the data frame with the data from the CSV file. There's no need to call `read.table()` on it again.

You can define column classes explicitly using `read_csv()` command from readr package (part of tidyverse):

```
install.packages(readr)
?readr::read_csv
```